# UWP SQL Server Connection String

Tags: .net, sql-server, uwp, connection-string

I have made a UWP app using Visual Studio 2017. Build it and it is running fine on my PC.
I have a local SQL database and put connection string in Resources.resw file.
I have made an app package of UWP app to run this on other PC.
[image: App Package of my UWP app]

Now I have to use this App on other PC, how can I change Connection String which was in Resources.resw for that PC.

Any help please?

Comment: app config is not there in UWP, you have to use Resources.resw/ xml/ json or a text file to read keys. But after right clicking the solution -> Store -> Create App packages... These all above type of files are not there in the App package!!

Comment: You can not change anything in package. You need to recreate package with proper connection string.

Comment: It is not like web app or desktop apps where you can of in deployment folder and change some config file.

Comment: Than how can I made such text that is editable when using a package on some other PC? Or any other work around for these type of issues??
 Any suggestions please

Comment: Actually you can do any external in file package? Two things you can do. First, allow user to enter connection string app and then store in application setting. Second, generate a text file in localdata folder and read/write from there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. One thing more, if I am going with a text file in localdata folder, than what to do in the case of tablet, or some windows using devices?

Comment: Check my answer below. I think I answered your question and all doubts. Still let me know if anything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SUGGESTION**

Actually you can not edit any external in file package.

Two things you can do. First, allow user to enter connection string app and then store in application setting. Second, generate a text file in `LocalFolder` and read/write from there.

You can access local folder using below code. Then you can create and read file from that folder. I advice you to create a folder on `LocalFolder`

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

Check [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) for how to write and read file from `StorageFolder`.

Comment: Thanks alot. Thumbs up!

Comment: Enjoy coding bother :)